# Vertx use uploaded images in html

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am able to upload files at the default location.

```
router.route().handler(
  BodyHandler.create()
    .setBodyLimit(500 * KB)
);    
router.post("/admin/add").handler(adminActions::createNewItem);
```

This body handler puts file in file-uploads. This is the code that uploads files:

```
public void createNewItem(RoutingContext context) {
    var request = context.request();
    var type = context.request().getFormAttribute("type");

    // other code...    

    for(var f : context.fileUploads()) {
      System.out.println(f.fileName());
    }            
  }
```

These are the files I have uploaded.

[image]

---

The file-uploads folder is at the root of my project, it's been automatically created. How do I reach the content of that folder to show the images in my html pages?

It's weird also, they have no extension...

Comment: via https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/groovy/#_serving_static_resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vert.x can [serve static content](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_serving_static_resources) with the static handler:

```
router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

The static handler `webroot` can be configured to point to your file uploads directory.

Yet I would recommend to consider security carefully if you are working on a public service with private data: if you expose the content of this directory without any protection, malicious users could try to download arbitrary content.

Comment: Could you provide a link on how to protect those directories?

Comment: No, because the way to protect really depend on the use case which is not specified here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what user tsegismont said I have to explain what's going on. I already used the statichandler but not in the proper way.

[image]

This is what I had before. The folder `resource` is inside src > main > java and I wanted to put pics there but it was not possible; this folder is compiled and I should restart the app every time that an upload occurs to see pictures. Not a good idea.

**SOLUTION**. I created a folder called `image-uploads` at the same level of `src` and then I used this code:

```
router.route("/uploads/imgs/*").handler(
      StaticHandler.create("image-uploads").setCachingEnabled(false)
);
```

And it works! When I call *https://mywebsite.com/uploads/imgs/something.png* vertx goes in the image-uploads folder and serves the images.

---

So if you want to upload images to the server and then see them in the browser via link, DO NOT upload files in `src` or subfolders. Do it outside src. Oh and when you upload do this:

```
router.route().handler(
  BodyHandler.create()
    .setUploadsDirectory("image-uploads")
    .setBodyLimit(400 * KB)
    .setMergeFormAttributes(true)
);
```

In this way `setUploadsDirectory` points to the folder outside src in which I put data.